# How to use use Firestore document field's HashMap key value and populate recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have just started learning android. I want to know is a way by which I can populate a RecyclerView using a firebase document's field which contains only the HashMap key and value. Sorry if I asked the wrong question. I just want to know if it is possible?[this is  the snapshot of my firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ags1q.png)

**Please note**- I know how to store the items (that I am storing in the map) as separate documents in a collection and make RecyclerView.  Currently, I am using this method only and populating the RecyclerView. But I don't want to store the items as a separate documents.

This is the required output needed...[Required reyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC2p2.jpg)

```
public class ModelTrans{
    Double RecentAmount;
    String TransText;
    String Transactionid;
    @ServerTimestamp
    Date date;
    int img;

    public ModelTrans() {
    }

    public ModelTrans(Double recentAmount, String transText, String transactionid, Date date, int img) {
        RecentAmount = recentAmount;
        Transtext = transText;
        Transactionid = transactionid;
        this.date = date;
        this.img = img;
    }

......other getter setters

}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far? What are you using Java or Kotlin?

Comment: @AlexMamo I am doing this with java.... I have tried is  that i have stored the items (that i am storing in map) as separate documents in a collection and made recylerview... But i dont want to create separate documents as the document read is very costly.

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that you have added those objects into a collection and it worked, you can do the same thing in a document as well. What you have to do is to create a reference that points to that particular document and then read it.

Each field of the document is an object of type `ModelTrans`. To get that data you should use the following lines of code:

```
joinedContestRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                List<ModelTrans> transList = new ArrayList<>();
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
                    //Iterate again and add the data to a transList.
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, I have used [DocumentSnapshot#getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()) method that returns an object of type Map<String, Object>. What you have to do now, is to iterate through the map and get the data inside it. You actually only need the values. In the end, simply add those values to a List, and then pass that List to an adapter. And that should be pretty much of it.

**Edit:**

Good point in your comment. I should have been added it from the beginning.

Yes, there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a single document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. So be aware of this limitation, otherwise, your writes may start to fail.

Comment: I would like to know how much item can the my document "JoinedContest" hold? I assume the maximum entries of map in the document mentioned as "JoinedContest "will be 700 to 1000.   So is this a good way to store the items in map key value way or Each item should be stored in a separate document?

Comment: Good point. Please see my updated answer. is it ok now?

Comment: thanks for the answer @Alexmamo..1 last thing i would like to ask..can you give me a link where suppose in this case i have 500 maps ...but i only want to show top 10 , then after the user scrolls next 10 will be read from firestore and loaded..next 10 further... I know its a diffrent Ques ..but can you share anything regarding this?

Comment: Pagination in Firestore works only with documents that exist in a collection. If you need to paginate the elements that come from a single document, in other words, paginate a List of `ModelTrans` objects, then you should implement that algorithm yourself.

Comment: Hey alex..i am not getting any idea after the line  Map<String, Object> map = document.getData(); How can i populate the data in recyclerview then.. I have iterated the data... But whats next ?  basically i am not able to do this , what you have said in the answer... `In the end, simply add those values to a List, and then pass that List to an adapter`    please help alex..

Comment: How can i add the key's value ... this ->>>  ```{date=Timestamp(seconds=1635622112, nanoseconds=76000000), img=2131230913, recentAmount=0.0, whatTrans=Joined a Contest, transactionid=8I3nyOerWBXy02i8mz9q}``` to a list?? Its is nested too....
I am doing this to add

 ```
 Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
                        while(itr.hasNext())
                        {
                            Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = itr.next();
                            modelTrans.add((entry.getValue());
                        }
```

Comment: I just updated my answer with how you can iterate the Map. As you already said, yes, it's a nested Map. So you should iterate twice. Your goal is to create a List<ModelTrans> and pass it to an adapter, so the data can be displayed in the RecyclerView.

Comment: But that **not** how you should deal when something doesn't work the way you expect. You don't have to remove the acceptance from an answer. You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up. Ok?

Comment: Thanks for your update to the answer alex.. My mistake i removed the accepted answer. I thought it was not helping me fully ..But thanks for your update .